# Save a google search results page

Tags: google-search

I am making a list of useful links I'm using google advanced search to find them, searching on only the domain "microsoft.com", however I have noticed that if I search again a few days after, the results change even though searching for the same thing in the same way.

So is there a way to save the search so the results don't change, and can therefore go back to the page number I left off at.

I Tried saving the page offline but this does not save each result web page or anything like that.

Comment: Can't you bookmark the page(s)

Comment: @whs I'm pretty sure each time the bookmark loads the search page, it will re-search the query and possibly generate different results.  Unless you mean to bookmark all 10-or-so results individually?

Comment: bookmarking each result is implausable, there are thousands of results